# How to determine length of memory map from /proc/self/maps in C?

Tags: c, linux, memory

Is it correct for a process to determine the length of a memory map by reading its entry in `proc/self/maps` and calculating the length as the difference between the offset and the ending address of the mapping?

I'm experimenting with closing memory maps via `munmap` that I did not explicitly open and if I've interpreted the man pages correctly, I need the starting address (offset) and the length to do so.

Comment: What is a _length of a memory map_? A virtual size?

Comment: @myaut Yes, the length argument is supposed to specify the length of the mapping.

Comment: It is the correct method of calculating the length. The problem is, if you happen to create several memory maps with the same protections (say, private read-write), it is possible they end up at consecutive addresses, and show up as a single entry. What you should do, is round your memory map sizes up to a multiple of `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`, and keep both the pointer and the length around in order to unmap it.

Comment: @NominalAnimal, thanks, I'll keep that in mind. The problem here is that I don't control the creation of these memory maps, that's why I'm forced to probe `/proc/self/maps` for information after the fact.  I upvoted your comment, if you post it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you considered interposing [`mmap()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (and `malloc()`/`calloc()`/`aligned_alloc()`/`posix_memalign()`, since they use `mmap()` internally for really large allocations)? That way you could keep track of them. GCC even provides [`__builtin_extract_return_addr(__builtin_return_address(depth))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html) to keep track of the exact callsite.